# How can I reconstitute a text file saved in a browser cache, gzipped?

Tags: apache, text, gzip, chromium

I just lost a couple of days of work to a crashing editor. My file is now an empty file, and the last backup I have is from 4 days ago.

I have the CSS file saved in my Chromium's cache, but it looks like this:

`http://myserver.example.com/style.css

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Mon, 04 Jul 2011 05:18:25 GMT

Last-Modified: Mon, 04 Jul 2011 01:10:47 GMT

Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 7588

Content-Type: text/css

00000000:  5e  01  00  00  02  08  00  00  be  45  ba  c7  cd  05  2e  00  ^........E......

00000010:  25  68  d9  c7  cd  05  2e  00  1d  01  00  00  48  54  54  50  %h..........HTTP

00000020:  2f  31  2e  31  20  32  30  30  20  4f  4b  00  44  61  74  65  /1.1 200 OK.Date

00000030:  3a  20  4d  6f  6e  2c  20  30  34  20  4a  75  6c  20  32  30  : Mon, 04 Jul 20

00000040:  31  31  20  30  35  3a  31  38  3a  32  35  20  47  4d  54  00  11 05:18:25 GMT.

(etc)

00000000:  1f  8b  08  00  00  00  00  00  00  03  cd  3d  fd  8f  db  b6  ...........=....

00000010:  92  3f  d7  7f  05  2f  8b  22  ed  c2  f2  87  fc  b1  6b  2f  .?.../."......k/

00000020:  1a  a0  09  5e  1e  f0  5e  7b  57  34  c5  dd  0f  87  83  21  ...^..^{W4.....!

00000030:  db  f2  5a  89  6c  f9  49  72  36  5b  63  ff  f7  e3  b7  86  ..Z.l.Ir6[c.....

00000040:  e4  50  1f  9b  4d  ef  52  34  b1  65  71  66  38  1c  ce  0c  .P..M.R4.eqf8...

00000050:  87  c3  e1  f0  9a  fc  e3  9c  1e  c9  3f  e2  94  fc  b1  8f  ..........?.....`

The entire file seems to be there, and I can get the text.

I'd like to get back the plain CSS file somehow.  I tried extracting the data, but gzip says it isn't gzip format.  But it doesn't seem to be gzip encoded (it's not binary, after all...). Is it base64 or something? I've had a hard time finding any info on this.

Comment: Would it be a gzip file *preceded* by a text header: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK...`

Comment: @pavium yes, the data in chrome's cache viewer is divided into two parts - one for the header, and one for the gzipped data.

Comment: But `gzip` doesn't recognise the gzipped data?

Comment: I've extracted the data and tried gzip, but it says it is not gzip format. Part of the problem is that the browser will not seem to give access to the raw data alone, only a hex dump as shown. I had to manually remove the hex and line numbers.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Chromium, but I'm surprised you can't access the file directly, *somehow*.

Comment: @pavium I agree, it should be simple? Yet I found the cache system appears exactly the same in Firefox and they both only give these hex dumps. I'm trying the directions in this article... http://www.frozax.com/blog/2011/05/recover-file-google-chrome-cache-gzipped/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the gzip header by extracting the hex data into an editor and searching for the header as per [gzip specification](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer). You should be able to do this by finding the end of the response body and selecting the previous 7588 bytes (you have this info in the response headers: `Content-Length: 7588`) - this should be the first character of the header.

Depending on the flags set in the header, gzip'd files may be ASCII or binary. You can determine if data are base64 encoded as base64 scheme encodings terminate with the `=` character. You can decode base64 [online](http://www.webutils.pl/Base64).

Alternatively you could try a tool such as [ChromeCacheViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html).

Comment: I've been trying, but for some reason gzip says the data is corrupted... and ChromeCacheViewer is Windows-only. However, I was able to use nirsoft's IE tool to get a copy of the file from the IE cache of another machine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The file looks gzip. It has the 1f8b header. Chrome stores the cached files as files, you just need to find them. Google for "location of chrome cache" and find it for your platform.

Comment: That should be the key, but for some reason I can't find the file in Chromium's directory! Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll get it worked out.